# Angular2 modal dialog

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, angular2-services, angular2-components

Structure of the app:

AppService
AppComponent -> HeroComponent -> WeaponComponent -> ButtonComponent

When someone clicks on the button (ButtonComponent), I would like to open a modal dialog in the AppComponent.

The best way I can think of is making a dialogObservable in the AppService. The ButtonComponent sets the observable and the AppComponent listens to it, and shows the dialog when there is a dialog set.

This already feels a bit messy.

But to make it worse, I also need buttons in the Dialog. When someone clicks on the "OK" button, I want to call an action from the WeaponComponent. Which is impossible, as far as I know. So what do I do? Create another observable in the service, and listen to it in the WeaponComponent.

This feels very messy, and I feel there must be a better way. I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem and I solved it by adding a modal in my root module component, and providing a `ModalService` accross my app.

`ModalService` is used as an event dispatcher, to dispatch the modal event.

Exemple with just signatures (to be easy to understand, implementation is not that hard):

```
@Injectable()
export class ModalService{
    public registerModal(name:string, onPop:()=>void):void;
    public popModal(name:string):void;
}
```

This way your `ModalComponent` can be anywhere (and you can have a lot of modals with different names) and you can pop it from anywhere since you just need to get the `ModalService`.

Note that to make this work, you have to use only one instance of `ModalService`, so it has to be declared in your `module.forRoot()` method.

EDIT:

To fix the context issue, you can declare your function and store it in a variable, this way:

```
function foo():any{
}
```

becomes

```
foo=():any => {
}
```

then you can pass the callback method to your modal using `this.foo`, it will not loose the context.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I'm doing it in a similar way. I create the modal in the service. But my biggest problem is how to handle the button clicks in the dialog. I want the click events of the buttons in the dialog to fire handlers in the component that opened the dialog, not in the dialog itself or in the service.

I can pass a function when opening the dialog, which works. But it get pulled out of its scope. So from within that event handler function, I can't access the original component anymore. So I'm still stuck with this.

Comment: Your modal shoud be in your module base component, this way it's still in its module scope but you place it using css to be fullscreen + top z-index and it's done.

Comment: In my situation this isn't possible, unfortunately. Also, a dialog is just an example, but could also be a different alert message somewhere in the app, but outside the component. For now I fixed it by passing "this" to the modal, which does the trick, though it's a bit messy...

Comment: I understand your problem with context, let me edit the answer to fix this for you :)

Comment: Awesome, did not know that! A bit more reading for people with a similar problem: https://toddmotto.com/es6-arrow-functions-syntaxes-and-lexical-scoping/